# Specify request command to use Guzzle PHP

Tags: curl, guzzle

I'm currently working with the IBM API and am trying to create a corpus using the Concept Insights Api.

I'm using Guzzle 6.x and am trying to achieve this, the curl command that needs to be run is this:

`curl -u user:password -X PUT -d '{}' 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/concept-insights/api/v2/corpora/xyz123/testCorpus'`

What I am doing is the following

`$this->getGuzzleClient()->request('PUT', 'v2/accounts', ['auth' => ['username', 'password']]);`

- The base_uri is set up correctly.
- The auth is correct

The response I get from IBM is:

`resulted in a '400 Bad Request' response: "error":"invalid corpus format",`

Comment: Guzzle has `put()` function separately, you can use that http://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/http-client/request.html#put-requests

Comment: I'm using a laster version of guzzle put I still get the same response when I use the `put` method.

Comment: add 'debug' => true to your request options array.  How is the curl request different from your guzzle request?